# Meanings of 0Xnumber in assembly instructions mov and add

Tags: assembly, system, disassembly, att

```
0000000000400ee0 <phase_1>:
  400ee0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400ee4:   be 00 24 40 00          mov    $0x402400,%esi
  400ee9:   e8 4a 04 00 00          callq  401338 <strings_not_equal>
  400eee:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400ef0:   74 05                   je     400ef7 <phase_1+0x17>
  400ef2:   e8 43 05 00 00          callq  40143a <explode_bomb>
  400ef7:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400efb:   c3                      retq
```

The above is the assembly code of a function that compares user's input string and a fixed string that is given by the program.

My question is that in `mov    $0x402400,%esi`, why the instruction doesn't store a decimal like value, namely, 4*16^5 + 2*16^3 + 4*16^1 into `%esi`. Instead, what it actually does is to store this address, `$0x402400`,  into `%esi`. So, is `$0x402400` an integer value that can't be dereferenced or at which the memory content can't be inspected) or address at which we can inspect the content (dereference)?

And why in this instruction `add    $0x8,%rsp`, `$0x8` is a integer value `8` to be stored in the register? Why at this occasion is it not an address that we can dereference?

PS: Any link to a textbook-like clear-cut definition will be much appreciated.

Comment: `$402400` is whatever you want it to be. Assembly language doesn't have an opinion one way or another

Comment: In this case however it's an address of a string. Strings can be arbitrary length hence you can't usually stuff them into a register (or an immediate operand) which is why you use an address instead. Note that writing `$4*16^5 + 2*16^3 + 4*16^1` would be exactly equivalent. It doesn't matter how you specify the same value.

Comment: @Jester I understand your point. Is there a way to quickly find that it is an address? What parameters to inspect in gdb, or syntax should I pay attention to?

Comment: To be sure you want to find a place where it is used as an address, that is dereferenced. In this case that's hidden inside the `strings_not_equal` or even lower. Heuristically, anything not obviously a sensible numeric constant can be cross-referenced with the process memory map to see if it is a valid address. In gdb you can examine it using the `x` command.

Comment: The fact that it's being passed as the 2nd arg to a function called `strings_not_equal` is the clue here.  Otherwise, look at memory contents at that address.  (`0x40...` is in the typical range for static data, so that's why we assume it's a pointer value rather than just an arbitrary integer.)

Comment: Thank you both. Now, I fully understand this syntax!